# minimumBet Appears to be Returning Incorrect Amount

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging, tutorials

I'm following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@merunasgrincalaitis/the-ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-and-deploy-a-fully-descentralized-dapp-in-ethereum-18f0cf6d7e0e), which seems like a great intro to solidity contracts, but I've got an issue where I don't see the same results as on the post.

When calling `minimumBet` from remix.solidity, the article claims it should return

```
    uint256: 1000000000000000
```

but for some reason I am getting

```
    "0": "uint256: 100000000000000000"
```

where my value has too many zeroes (2 to many).

Can anyone explainw hy this is happening?

Here is my copy of the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Casino {
    address owner;
    uint public minimumBet = 100 finney; // Equal to 0.1 ether
    uint public totalBet;
    uint public numberOfBets;
    uint public maxAmountOfBets = 100;
    address[] public players;

    struct Player {
        uint amountBet;
        uint numberSelected;
    }

    // allows us to call playerInfo[here_goes_his_address].amountBet
    mapping(address => Player) playerInfo;

    function Casino(uint _minimumBet) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        if(_minimumBet != 0) minimumBet = _minimumBet;
    }

    // Fallback function in case someone sendes ether to the contract so it doesn't get lost
    function() payable public {}

    function kill() public {
        if(msg.sender == owner)
            selfdestruct(owner);
    }

    function checkPlayerExists(address player) constant returns(bool) {
        for(uint i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if(players[i] == player) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // To bet for a number between 1 and 10 both inclusive
    function bet(uint number) public payable {
        assert(checkPlayerExists(msg.sender) == false);
        assert(number >= 1 && number <= 10);
        assert(msg.value >= minimumBet);

        playerInfo[msg.sender].amountBet = msg.value;
        playerInfo[msg.sender].numberSelected = number;
        numberOfBets += 1;
        players.push(msg.sender);
        totalBet += msg.value;

        if(numberOfBets >= maxAmountOfBets) generateNumberWinner();
    }

    // Generates a number between 1 and 10
    function generateNumberWinner() public {
        uint numberGenerated = block.number % 10 + 1; // This isn't secure
        distributePrizes(numberGenerated);
    }

    // Sends the corresponding ether to each winner depending on the total bets
    function distributePrizes(uint numberWinner) public {
        address[100] memory winners; // we have to create a temporary in memory array with fixed size
        uint count = 0; // This is the count for the array winners

        for (uint i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            address playerAddress = players[i];
            if(playerInfo[playerAddress].numberSelected == numberWinner) {
                winners[count] = playerAddress;
                count++;
            }
            delete playerInfo[playerAddress]; // Delete all the players
        }

        players.length = 0; // Delete all the players array

        uint winnerEtherAmount = totalBet / winners.length; // How much each winner gets

        for(uint j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            // Check that the address in this fixed array is not empty
            if(winners[j] != address(0)) winners[j].transfer(winnerEtherAmount);
        }
    }
}
```

Note as per the tutorial I am doing this with metamask on the test network. Thanks in advance!

#### What I tried already

- killing the contract and recreating
- hard refresh (ctrl + f5), which seems to solve a few other issues

Answer (score 0):

This appears to just be a typo. The screenshot above that text shows the same number of zeroes that you're getting. Try contacting the author of the post to get clarification.